# gtest testing function with subscriber reference

Tags: ros, node-handle, gtest, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using gtest for writing test suites for my robot. Im trying to test a function that i use to convert my twist message being sent from the Nav Stack or joystick (cmd_vel topic) that is then converted into my individual wheel velocities for my roboteq motor controller. This function that i am testing is used in the cmd_vel subscriber callback in my roboteq driver node. So normally, when the callback is fired, i pass the reference of the twist, into my function like so (i type def'd geometry_msgs::Twist to TTwist, and TWheelMsg is my custom msg, also type def'd)

```
void    RosRoboteqDrv::CmdVelCallback(const TTwist::ConstPtr& twist_velocity)
{
    _wheelVelocity = RosRoboteqDrv::ConvertTwistToWheelVelocity(twist_velocity);
```

Where my my conversion function is defined like so:

```
TWheelMsg   ConvertTwistToWheelVelocity(const TTwist::ConstPtr& twist_velocity);
```

In my gtest class, im not sure how i can use this ConvertTwtistToWheelVelocity function since it is passing a reference. I tried looking up in the API docs where the reference originated from, and found that in the node handle subscriber template [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/hydro-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h#L437) it passes a boost shared pointer, which in my case i passed type geometry_msgs::Twist. So then i looked inside of the geometry_msgs source file, and found this:

```
typedef  ::geometry_msgs::Twist_< std::allocator< void > >
```

Can someone please tell me what should i do to be able to pass some value (clearly has to be reference) into the ConvertTwistToWheelVelocity function? I dont know what to do since std::allocator is the template type.

Since in the API docs it says that the node handle subscribe function is a template

---

**EDIT:** here is what my subscriber call looks like:

```
_sub = _nh.subscribe("cmd_vel", 1, &RosRoboteqDrv::CmdVelCallback, this);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190466/gtest-testing-function-with-subscriber-reference/) by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ConstPtrs in ROS behave like boost::shared_ptr, and you can use them similarly.

This should probably look something like:

```
// .. fill in your message fields
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
msg.linear.x = 42;
geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr msg_p(new geometry_msgs::Twist(msg));

// call your callback
driver.CmdVelCallback(msg_p);
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-20**:
Going to try this out in a few hours after work. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks